# R ggplot text on grid lines denoting grid line value

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to make the the value of the grid line appear on the grid line in `ggplot2`?

I have a very large plot that I want to display the grid line value on intermittently throughout the plot, so when you are zoomed in you can easily tell what the value is.  The only way I can currently think to do that is to add the labels with another data frame or something with the label and the x, y position.  I was wondering if there was a more efficient way or an actual built in mechanism to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option built-in to do this specifically, but it is pretty straightforward using `expand.grid` to create the grid points and labels, then simply draw the result on with `geom_text`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

gridlines <- expand.grid(Petal.Width = seq(0, 2, 0.5), 
                         Sepal.Length = seq(4, 8), 
                         Species = "setosa")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = gridlines, color = "gray50", aes(label = Sepal.Length), 
            angle = 90, vjust = -0.5, nudge_y = 0.25) +
  geom_text(data = gridlines, color = "gray50", aes(label = Petal.Width),
            vjust = -0.5, nudge_x = 0.5) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>